# Why doesnt alert((parseInt("3"))++); run in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript

Why doesn't

```
alert((parseInt("3"))++); 
alert(parseInt("3")++); 
alert(++(parseInt("3"))); 
alert(++parseInt("3"));
```

run in Google Chrome, but

```
alert(parseInt("3") + 1);
alert(1 + (parseInt("3"));
```

runs just fine ?

I've tried looking into the docs, but can't find a reason.

Answer (score 2):

`++` increments the value in the property or variable on the left hand side.

The return value of a function isn't a property or a variable.

Comment: What's a regular number? Do you mean a number literal? If it did, then `3++; alert(3)` would display "4". That would be awful.